# Shorten a dataframe by conditions in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
Bestand = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A123', 'IE00B0M62Q58', 'B333'],
        'Name': ['Example A', 'iShares MSCI World UCITS ETF', 'Example B'],
        'Anbieter': ['Test1', 'iShares', 'Test2'],
         'value': [20, 50, 7]})

etf_list = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['IE00B4X9L533', 'IE00B0M62Q58', 'LU0292097234'],
        'Name': ['HSBC MSCI WORLD UCITS ETF', 'iShares MSCI World UCITS ETF', 
        'FTSE 100 Income UCITS ETF 1D'], 'Anbieter': ['HSBC', 'iShares', 'Xtrackers']})
```

The data frame Bestand should be reduced by all the rows where ISIN is equal like in the dataframe etf_llist

The new dataframe Bestand should look like:

```
Bestand = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A123', 'B333'],
        'Name': ['Example A', 'Example B'],
        'Anbieter': ['Test1', 'Test2'],
         'value': [20, 7]})
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via `isin()` method:

```
Bestand=Bestand[~Bestand['ISIN'].isin(etf_list['ISIN'].unique())]
```

output of `Bestand`:

```
    ISIN    Name    Anbieter    value
0   A123    Example A   Test1   20
2   B333    Example B   Test2   7
```

If needed use `reset_index()` method:

```
Bestand=Bestand.reset_index(drop=True)
```